# \refstepcounter within \subsection breaks \ref to \subsubsection

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Usually a `\ref` to a `\subsubsection` gives `1.1.1` (from the parent `\subsection`). Sample:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap}
\section{sec}
\subsection{sub}
\subsubsection{subsub}
label \label{subsub}

\section{sec2}
\ref{subsub}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I add and use a counter, indicated line breaks output of `\ref{subsub}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{someCounter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap}
\label{chap}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec}
\label{sec}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\subsection{sub}
\label{sub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %this breaks \ref{subsub}

\subsubsection{subsub}
\label{subsub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec2}
\ref{chap} :: \ref{sec} :: \ref{sub} :: \ref{subsub}

\end{document}
```

Output (last `3` should be `1.1.1`:

[image]

What is the reason for this unexpected behavior? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. `\subsubsection{subsub}` does not have a number, thus it cannot be referenced. Internally `\refstepcounter{subsubsection}` is not called, because the default setting of counter `secnumdepth` excludes `\subsubsection` and the lower section commands `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` from getting numbers. `\label{subsub}` therefore references the `\subsection` before in the first case and the `\refstepcounter{someCounter}` before in the second case.

### Unnumbered sections can be referenced by name and page number

The example uses package `nameref` for referencing the name, another package is `titleref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{someCounter}
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap}
\label{chap}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec}
\label{sec}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\subsection{sub}
\label{sub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %this breaks \ref{subsub}

\subsubsection{subsub}
\label{subsub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec2}
\ref{chap} :: \ref{sec} :: \ref{sub} ::
section ``\nameref{subsub}'' on page \pageref{subsub}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result reference by name and page number]

### Subsubsections with number:

The section numbering depth can be increased by `\stepcounter{secnumdepth}` or setting it to `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` for numbering section levels including subsubsections:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{someCounter}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap}
\label{chap}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec}
\label{sec}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\subsection{sub}
\label{sub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %this breaks \ref{subsub}

\subsubsection{subsub}
\label{subsub}
\refstepcounter{someCounter} %ok

\section{sec2}
\ref{chap} :: \ref{sec} :: \ref{sub} :: \ref{subsub}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with numbered subsubsection]

Comment: No number, no reference. Seems reasonable. So the "1.1.1" is actually the "unexpected" part.